# How to compile a Unity/Vuforia project to iOs on Windows?

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I need to compile my project to iOS version, but I don't have a Mac so I can't download Xcode and iOS sdk. Any ideas??

Comment: Joana - unfortunately it's absolutely impossible to create iOS builds, unless you have a Mac.  This has been asked many times so you can get some more info.  Sorry for the bad news, ciao!

Comment: One solution is find a friend who has a mac, and export your project file, and let your friend help you build on Xcode

Comment: There is an iOS project builder for Windows currently advertised on AssetStore. It is $40 which is less than a Mac but I can't tell about working or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of tutorials, here's [a random one](https://www.alltechbuzz.net/install-xcode-on-windows-for-ios-sdk/).

First, make sure that your CPU supports hardware virtualization, so called VT-x. For Intel, here's the [compatibility list](http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology). You can get your model number from system properties (Control Panel > System and Security > System > Processor, something like that, depends on your Windows version). If it does not support VT-x, don't even try.

I ended up with buying a MacBook :)